# I am using tablepress to insert an image as a link and want it to open in a new tab

Tags: html, wordpress, tablepress

```
[caption id="attachment_7233" align="alignnone" width="300"]<a href="https://wickedninjagames.com/lead-game-admin-role/"><img src="https://wickedninjagames.com/wp-content/uploads/WNG-Lead-Admin-300x250.jpg" alt="wng lead game admin" width="300" height="250" class="size-medium wp-image-7233" /></a> wng lead game admin[/caption]
```

Insert image as link, want it to open in new tab

Answer (score 1):

To open link into new tab juste add attribute `target` with value `_blank`

```
[caption id="attachment_7233" align="alignnone" width="300"]<a href="https://wickedninjagames.com/lead-game-admin-role/" target="_blank"><img src="https://wickedninjagames.com/wp-content/uploads/WNG-Lead-Admin-300x250.jpg" alt="wng lead game admin" width="300" height="250" class="size-medium wp-image-7233" /></a> wng lead game admin[/caption]
```